# Installshield LE with chained package

Tags: c#, installshield

Does anyone know if it is possible to create a chained package with LE?

I can create an installation msi with my project (C#) however I need to embed the MSSQL LocalDB installation with my project msi as it is an application requirement & I don't want my users to have to do this separately. Am trying to create a seamless installation for them.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

InstallShield can bootstrap/chain packages together using a feature called Setup Prerequisites.  Unfortunately, InstallShield Limited Edition doesn't have the feature to create .PRQ (prereqs) files.

What I would do is throw InstallShield Professional on a VM and use the Prerequisite Editor to create the .PRQ file and then copy it into your ISLE development environment.   Add this to your installer and InstallShield will preinstall the LocalDB engine.

See:

[Using InstallShield 12 to Install .NET Framework 3.0](http://blog.iswix.com/2006/11/using-installshield-12-to-install-net.html)