# Silent Install Crystal reports

Tags: winforms, deployment, crystal-reports

I developed a WinForms Application that use Crystal reports. When I try to install my application on another machine, I need to install CRRuntime_XXbits_13_0_2.msi before

My question is: Is there a way to silently install the Crystal Reports runtime? How can I include it in my setup project?

thanks to all.

Comment: Why kind of setup project are you using? Wix? InstallShield?

Comment: what version and edition of installshield?

Comment: I don't know. I'm using VS 2013.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using InstallShield Limited Edition, you have a few options.

1. InstallShield can chain installer files (.MSI) if you use it to create a InstallShield Prerequisite file (.PRQ) that can be added on the "Redistributables" screen ... but you can't create those files with the Limited Edition. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23743454/installshield-le-with-chained-package) for more information.
2. On the same "Redistributables" screen, you could also add merge modules. On the same page where you download the Crystal Reports installer, you can [download merge modules](http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-7824), though the specific support pack you listed doesn't appear to be available.

That version is pretty limited though. If your setup gets any more complicated, I'd switch to something else.

Answer (score 0):

Simply start the msi file with the parameter "/qn /norestart ALLUSERS=2". successful return codes are 0 and 3010.